# Regular expression for validate multiple mobile number

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language, regex-group

What should be the Regular expression for validating multiple Indian mobile numbers which are separated by commas `,` like: .

```
+919883443344,+91-9883443344,919883443344,91-9883443344,09883443344,9883443344
```

That format should be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the phones string and evaluate one by one. Try this function:

```
function validatePhonesString(phonesString){
    var PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX = /(?:\+?91-?\d{10})|(?:0?\d{10})(\,(?:\+?91-?\d{10})|(?:0?\d{10}))*/;
    var valid = true;
    var phones = [];
    phones = phonesString.split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
            var phone = phones[i];
            if (phone === '' || !PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX.test(phone)) {
                valid = false;
            }
    }   

     return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex !

```
(\+\d{2}|\d{2}-|\d{2}|\d{1})?\d{10}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?:\+?91-?\d{10})|(?:0?\d{10})(\,(?:\+?91-?\d{10})|(?:0?\d{10}))*
```

**tested on:**

https://regex101.com/r/lQ6nAU/1/